# Update object state by using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a question about changing the value of a property within an object using Hooks, How do I do that ?

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({id: '', name: '', email: '', entries: 0, joined: ''})
let count = 5;
```

And I would like to update the value of the property"entries"  with a variable "count".

How do I do that with setUser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work;

```
setUser({
  ...user,
  entries: count
});
```

Comment: @azntony `setUser(user=>({
  ...user,
  entries: count
}));` would be a saver option depending on where you set it (like in an effect or a function passed to useCallback)